# ::first-letterで文字サイズを大きくすると、Safariでは後続の文字の位置が上にそろってしまう

Tags: html, css

`::first-letter`を使ったとき、下図のように`Chrome`に1行目と2行目の間に空間が普通より大きくなって、`Safari`には1行目の文字が上がりました：

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

`line-height`の設定は変えませんでした。

[こちら](https://jsfiddle.net/nf4sfb02/)の例を`Safari`ブラウザーで開いてください。

```css
table{
    font-family:"Century Gothic", Arial, "Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro",  Meiryo, sans-serif; 
 
}

tr{}

td{
 height:246px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 text-align: left;
 vertical-align: top;
 font-size: 16px;
 position: relative;
}

td::first-letter{
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    魚とはウエブデザインにおいてただ空いている空間を本文で満たすための内容だ。ただし本文の有意義さにはこだわりがない。
  </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: HTMLソースはどのようになっていますか。vertical-alignを指定しているのはなぜでしょうか。

Comment: 私のHTMLに上記の本文は表 (`table`) に入っています。ですから、`vertical-align`の設定は大丈夫でしょうか。

Comment: HTMLソースを見せて差し障りがないのであれば質問本文に記載した方が回答しやすいかと……

Comment: すみませんでした。[こちら](https://jsfiddle.net/nf4sfb02/)をSafariで開いて、ご覧ください。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vertical-align`を適用したいのは`<td>`にであってその中のテキストでは無いので、`vertical-align:top`を`<tr>`に設定し、スタイルの継承を止めるために`<td>`に`vertical-align:baseline`を設定すれば期待通りになると思います。

```css
table {
  font-family: "Century Gothic", Arial, "Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro", Meiryo, sans-serif;
}
tr {
  vertical-align: top;
}
td {
  float: none;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  height: 246px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
}
td::first-letter {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
p::first-letter {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
p,
#with::first-letter {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table style="background-color:yellow; padding:2px;">
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color:red;">
      魚とはウエブデザインにおいてただ空いている空間を本文で満たすための内容だ。ただし本文の有意義さにはこだわりがない。
    </td>
    <td style="background-color:blue;">
      魚とはウエブデザインにおいてただ空いている空間を本文で満たすための内容だ。ただし本文の有意義さにはこだわりがない。
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>
  魚とはウエブデザインにおいてただ空いている空間を本文で満たすための内容だ。ただし本文の有意義さにはこだわりがない。
</p>
<p id="with">
  魚とはウエブデザインにおいてただ空いている空間を本文で満たすための内容だ。ただし本文の有意義さにはこだわりがない。
</p>
```

ちなみに[仕様](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-letter)的にはSafariの挙動が正しいのだと思います。`::first-letter`には`vertical-align`が`float:none`である場合に限って適応できるとあり、Safariでは`float:none`ではご質問の様に適応され、`float:left`などにすると無視されるのが確認できます。

> These are the properties that apply to :first-letter pseudo-elements: font properties, 'text-decoration', 'text-transform', 'letter-spacing', 'word-spacing' (when appropriate), 'line-height', 'float', 'vertical-align' (only if 'float' is 'none'), margin properties, padding properties, border properties, color property, background properties.

---

追記
と思ったのですが引用した部分は`::first-letter`に直接指定可能なプロパティについてで、Firefoxで`vertical-align: top;`を`::first-letter`に適応したらSafariの`<td>`内と同じになったので、やはりSafariがおかしいっぽいです。感じとしては`vertical-align: top;`が`::first-letter`にまで継承した様な挙動になってますが（なのに`::first-letter`に`vertical-align: baseline;`を指定しても直ら無いのでその説明もちょって合わない気が…）、[継承に関する仕様](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html)に`vertical-align`は継承されないとあるので結局Safariがおかしい様です。

Comment: お時間、誠にありがとうございます！非常に助けてくださいました＾＾